# Divide the number into different groups according to the adjacency relationship

Tags: r, adjacency-list

I have a dataframe that stores adjacency relations. I want to divide numbers into different groups according to this dataframe. The dataframe are as follows:

```r
df = data.frame(from=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5), to=c(1,3,2,3,4,1,2,3,2,4,5,4,5))
df
   from to
1     1  1
2     1  3
3     2  2
4     2  3
5     2  4
6     3  1
7     3  2
8     3  3
9     4  2
10    4  4
11    4  5
12    5  4
13    5  5
```

In above dataframe, number `1` has links with number `1` and `3`, number `2` has links with number `2`, `3`, `4`, so number `1` can not be in same group with number `3` and number `2` can not be in same group with number `3` and number `4`. In the end, groups can be `c(1, 2, 5)` and `c(3, 4)`.

I wonder how to program it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace the values of `to` with `NA` when `from` and `to` are equal.

```r
df2 <- transform(df, to = replace(to, from == to, NA))
```

Then recursively bind each row of the data if `from` of the latter row has not appeared in `to` of the former rows.

```r
Reduce(function(x, y) {
  if(y$from %in% x$to) x else rbind(x, y)
}, split(df2, 1:nrow(df2)))

#    from to
# 1     1 NA
# 2     1  3
# 3     2 NA
# 4     2  3
# 5     2  4
# 12    5  4
# 13    5 NA
```

Finally, you could extract unique elements for the both columns to get the two groups.

---

The overall pipeline should be

```r
df |>
  transform(to = replace(to, from == to, NA)) |>
  (\(dat) split(dat, 1:nrow(dat)))() |>
  Reduce(f = \(x, y) if(y$from %in% x$to) x else rbind(x, y))
```

Comment: Nice solution! But if you remove rows where `from` and `to` are equal, in some cases, this will drop some node (eg: when from `5` to `4` is not exist, you will drop number `5`). To avoid this ,I have proposed an answer below, but it is very clumsy. Looking forward to your update！

Comment: @showteth You are right! How about replacing the values of `to` with NA when `from` and `to` are equal? This works when `from 5 to 4` does not exist. See my update.

Comment: Wonderful solution!

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Darren Tsai has solved this problem, but with some flaw.

Following is a very clumsy solution:

```
df = data.frame(from=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5), to=c(1,3,2,3,4,1,2,3,2,4,5,4,5))
df.list = lapply(split(df,df$from), function(x){
  x$to
})
group.idx = rep(1, length(unique(df$from)))
for (i in seq_along(df.list)) {
  df.vec <- df.list[[i]]
  curr.group = group.idx[i]
  remain.vec = setdiff(df.vec, i)
  for (j in remain.vec) {
    if(group.idx[j] == curr.group){
      group.idx[j] = curr.group + 1
    }
  }
}
group.idx
[1] 1 1 2 2 1
```